# How can I format my Python code with autopep8 using VS Code's format on save feature?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyproject.toml, autopep8

I am trying to format my Python code automatically using the format on save feature in vs Code.
I have installed the `autopep8` package and added the following configuration to my `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.autopep8]
in-place = true
aggressive = 2
```

when I try like `autopep8 test.py` it is working. However, when I try to format my code using the format on save feature, I get the following error message:

```
--in-place cannot be used with standard input
```

How can I resolve this error and format my code using `autopep8` with desired options?
and my vs code settings looks like:

```
  // Python
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
    
  },
 
"python.formatting.provider": "none",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your settings like the following codes:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
  "in-place = true",
  "aggressive = 2"
],
```

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_general-formatting-settings) for more detials.

Comment: i did it but not working, still the same error

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the relevant settings in `pyproject.toml`. If you delete the settings in `pyproject.toml`, can it solve the problem?

Comment: @Davood I've edited my answer, will it work?

Comment: no unfortunately, still not working

Comment: @Davood Have you tried black? I need to know whether it's the problem about autopep8 installed in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Davood,** Go ahead and create a .vscode folder in the root of your project. write a settings.json file in there and add the following configuration:

```
{
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "120"
  ],
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[python]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.rulers": [
      79,
      120
    ],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps pal, happy coding!!